# Derived Chow varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, derived-algebraic-geometry

I recently encountered the "Hidden Smoothness Principle" envisioned by Deligne, Drinfeld, Beilinson, Kontsevich that singularities occurring in certain moduli spaces is the consequence of working with the truncations of a hypothetical derived moduli space that is smooth. I have to admit that I do not have much knowledge about derived algebraic geometry but after some search I realized that there is a construction of derived Hilbert schemes that satisfies the expected properties of smoothness and the possibility of recovering the classical Hilbert scheme after truncation. So my question is whether there is something similar for Chow varieties/schemes or not? (or can there be one?).

Comment: Probably there is no hidden smoothness for Chow.  When a moduli space with hidden smoothness has dimension that equals the “expected dimension”, then the moduli space is LCI.  But Chow varieties of zero dimensional cycles are simply symmetric powers, and these are rarely LCI.

Comment: @Jason Starr "Hidden smoothness" in the sense of the Ciocan-Fontanine--Kapranov papers just amounts to existence of a derived moduli space with a perfect cotangent complex, since charts which are smooth in their sense then always exist locally. Although only LCI schemes have perfect cotangent complexes, the cotangent complex of a  derived scheme/space/stack being perfect doesn't imply that the cotangent complex of its underived truncation is so.

Comment: @JonPridham. Yes, I know that.  This is the reason that I added the hypothesis that the “expected dimension” equals the dimension.

Comment: @Jason Starr OK, I see. You're saying if there exists a derived enhancement of Chow, it won't be of the expected dimension, so unlikely to be a natural moduli functor.